# how can i combine maps in hive across multiple rows?

Tags: hive, aggregate-functions

I have a hive table like

```
string id,  map<string attr_name,double attr_value> attrs
```

but the structure isn't what you'd expect.   each attr has its own row, like:

```
1   height:180.0
1   weight:76.0
2   height:170.0
2   weight:74
```

how can i write a hive query that collapses these into something like

```
1   height:180,weight:76.0
2   height:170,weight:74.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate properties using `min()` or `max()` `group by id`, assemble string with delimiters and convert to map using `str_to_map()` function:

```
select id, str_to_map(concat_ws(',',concat('height',':',cast(max(attrs['height']) as string)),concat('weight',':',cast(max(attrs['weight']) as string))),',',':') as attrs
from
(--this is your table data, just replace the subquery (s) with your table
 select 1 as id, map('height',180.0) as attrs union all
 select 1 as id, map('weight',76.0) as attrs union all
 select 2 as id, map('height',170.0) as attrs union all
 select 2 as id, map('weight',74.0) as attrs
 )s
 group by id;

OK
1       {"height":"180.0","weight":"76.0"}
2       {"height":"170.0","weight":"74.0"}
Time taken: 74.219 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Add more properties and replace subquery s with your table;

Comment: thx - i want to have a map that has all the attrs at the end, not all attrs merged into one number

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob First example does exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregator function collect_set.[Source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

```
select id, collect_set(attr)
from table
group by id;
```